# Uniqueness of homomorphism in universal property of localisation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, localization, universal-property

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and let $D$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$ containing $1$. Define $D^{-1}R$ in the usual way (as the quotient $(R\times D)/\sim$ with $(r,d) \sim (s, e) \iff x(er - ds) = 0$ for some $x \in D$) and call these equivalence classes $r/d$.

The construction comes from Dummit and Foote; there is a commutative ring $D^{-1}R$ and a ring homomorphism $\pi : R \to D^{-1}R$ satisfying the universal property: for any homomorphism $\psi:R \to S$ of commutative rings sending $1$ to $1$ and such that $\psi(d)$ is a unit in $S$ for every $d \in D$ there is a $\textbf{unique}$ homomorphism $\Psi:D^{-1}R \to S$ such that $\Psi \circ \pi = \psi.$

The existence is fairly easy to understand but the uniqueness seems oddly handwavy. In the text, it is remarked that $\Psi$ is unique because every element of $D^{-1}R$ can be written as a product $(r/1)(d/1)^{-1}$. The text then goes on to explain that the value of $\Psi$ on an element of the form $x/1$ is uniquely determined by $\psi$, since $\Psi(x/1) = \Psi(\pi(x)) = \psi(x)$. Finally, the text explains that the value of $\Psi$ on any element $u^{-1}$ is uniquely determined by $\Psi(u)$ for any unit $u$.

I don't see any explanation in the conclusions that these values are uniquely determined; the text simply SAYS that they are uniquely determined without any actual proof (it seems).

Am I missing something that is obvious? I understand that homomorphisms send units to units so this seems reasonable, but simply saying that the images of these elements under $\Psi$ are uniquely determined seems uniquely handwavy.

Comment: $\psi = \Psi \circ \pi$ determines $\Psi$ on $\pi(R)$. And $\Psi(u)\cdot \Psi(u^{-1}) = \Psi(u\cdot u^{-1}) = \Psi(1) = 1$ shows $\Psi(u^{-1}) = \Psi(u)^{-1}$ for a unit $u$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand this but what is it that makes this determination unique? I seem to have this issue with any universal property I stumble across. Also, $\psi$ factors as $\Psi \circ \pi = \psi$, not sure if that was a typo?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand, so I need to guess what might help. Generally, a homomorphism (whether of vector spaces, groups, rings, …) is uniquely determined by its values on a generating set. Here, $\pi(R)$ is a generating set of $D^{-1}R$ since every $\xi \in D^{-1}R$ can be written as $\pi(x)\cdot \pi(d)^{-1}$ for some $x,d\in R$. (Yes, that was a typo. Fixed now.)

Comment: There is no difference between "determines" and "determines uniquely"...what do you think "unique" means that is different from what you have?

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought that unique determination and "determination" were different unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove uniqueness, let $\Psi,\Psi':D^{-1}R\to S$ be two ring homomorphisms such that $\Psi'\circ\pi=\psi$ and $\Psi\circ\pi=\psi$.
Let $x\in D^{-1}R$.
Then there exists $r\in R$ and $d\in D$ such that $x=r/d$ hence $(d/1)x=(r/1)$ that's $\pi(d)x=\pi(r)$.
Then $\Psi\circ\pi(d)\Psi(d)=\Psi\circ\pi(r)$ from which $\psi(d)\Psi(x)=\psi(r)$ in $S$.
Similarly, $\psi(d)\Psi'(x)=\psi(r)$, thus $\psi(d)\Psi'(x)=\psi(d)\Psi(x)$.
Since $\psi(d)$ is invertible in $S$ (recall $d\in D$), we get $\Psi(x)=\Psi'(x)$.
By the arbitrariety of $x$, we get $\Psi=\Psi'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)